# how to download output artifacts from AWS sagemaker (Python)

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker

I have a code similar to this one

```
'''
from sagemaker.experiments import Experiment
from sagemaker.experiments import Run
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sagemaker import Session


sagemaker_session = Session(default_bucket="data-science")

# Define an experiment
experiment_name = 'my-experiment-'
experiment_run_name = experiment_name + "1"
# Create the experiment
# experiment = Experiment.create(experiment_name=experiment_name)
# save experiments
with Run(experiment_name = experiment_name, run_name = experiment_run_name, artifact_bucket = "data-science") as run:
    # Your code to generate and plot data
    x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    y = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.xlabel('X-axis')
    plt.ylabel('Y-axis')
    plt.title('My Plot')

    # Save the plot as an image file
    plot_filename = 'my_plot.png'
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig(plot_filename)

    # Log the plot as an artifact
    run.log_artifact(plot_filename, plot_filename)
'''
```

After running the code, I can see experiment-1 on the list of experiments, and I can also see "my_plot.png" listed as an artifact output, however I cannot visualise the plot. So my question is: Where does sagemaker save the output artifacts? Is there a way to output the path were the artifacts are stored?
Thanks